# Exclude MySQL result rows where count is zero

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN u.account_new = 1 THEN u.user_id END) AS new_user, 
    COUNT(u.user_id) AS all_users, 
    c.country_name AS country 
FROM users u, countries c 
WHERE u.country_id = c.country_id 
GROUP BY u.country
```

This shows a count of new users and total users grouped by country. I'd like to exclude rows where the count of new users is zero, but I'm not sure how to do this in the above SQL. At the moment I'm skipping them in PHP but thought there might be a better way to write the query.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: There are just fewer than 200 countries in the world, so I doubt that this is ever going to be your bottleneck.

Comment: add `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN u.account_new = 1 THEN u.user_id END)>0`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:
(note the HAVING clause)

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN u.account_new = 1 THEN u.user_id END) AS new_user, 
    COUNT(u.user_id) AS all_users, 
    c.country_name AS country 
FROM users u, countries c 
WHERE u.country_id = c.country_id 
GROUP BY u.country 
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN u.account_new = 1 THEN u.user_id END) > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

This includes a better reading improvement for counting new users:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(u.account_new=1) AS new_user, 
    COUNT(u.user_id) AS all_users, 
    c.country_name AS country 
FROM users u, countries c 
WHERE u.country_id = c.country_id 
GROUP BY u.country 
HAVING SUM(u.account_new=1)>0
```

Comment: You changed the meaning of `new_user`.

Comment: Why? With `new_user` he counts all users having `account_new=1`. My statement will sum up the result of logic statement `account_new=1`. The result is the same, isn't it?

Comment: `CASE WHEN u.account_new = 1 THEN u.user_id END`, not `CASE WHEN u.account_new = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: No, his statement returns `NULL` for users not having `account_new=1` so these rows are not counted. In my example these users get a `0` and won't be summed up too.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: You are probably missing the fact that in the comment it was COUNT and now it's SUM. In any event, the two methods are indeed equivalent. In the end, *rabudde* simply chose the simpler looking one.

Comment: @Andriy: Ah, gotcha. That's the difference. :)